# Is it possible to use getDataImage on a canvas that has undergone transformation in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to grab a particular part of the canvas and then put that image back onto the canvas in a very particular way. However, it seems that the get and put ImageData methods work on an absolute canvas that is not affected by image manipulations. Is there any way to use translations with the get and put dataImage operations in HTML5?

I have a line drawing that occurs at an angle and I want to capture that image, put it on its own canvas, do some processing on it, and then put it back on the canvas at that exact angle and position. I originally thought I could do this by repositioning the canvas based on the position and angle of the drawing, but this did not work because get and put dataImage use absolute rather than relative coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the data to an image, and draw the image to the new canvas for processing. That way, you will get what appears on the canvas, exactly as it appears.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    processingCanvas.width = this.width;
    processingCanvas.height = this.height;
    processingCanvas.drawImage(this,0,0);
}

img.src = originalCanvas.toDataURL();
```

And boom, it's on your processing canvas (after you wait for it some). As long as you don't have an absolutely HUGE canvas, this method should work rather quickly. Just get everything you want, and make sure it is visible on the canvas. And then you know how to get the processed data back to the other canvas. I hope this was what you were looking for.